# How to install Pixel saver on Gnome 3.10

Tags: gnome, titlebar

How to install Pixel saver Gnome extension on Gnome 3.10

Answer (score 1):

To use Pixel Saver in Gnome version 3.10, you need an older version of the extension, as noted in the extensions' [github README page](https://github.com/deadalnix/pixel-saver)

> Version 1.3 will be the last version to support gnome shell prior to 3.12 .

1. First grab the tarball of version 1.3 from [it's release page](https://github.com/deadalnix/pixel-saver/releases).
2. Then extract the tarball to get a `pixel-saver@deadalnix.me` folder.
3. Copy that folder in Gnome shell extensions directory

   ```
   cp -r pixel-saver@deadalnix.me -t ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
   ```
4. Activate it using

   ```
   gnome-shell-extension-tool -e pixel-saver@deadalnix.me
   ```

Here is the project's [Github page](https://github.com/deadalnix/pixel-saver)

Newer version of the extension can be directly installed from Gnome Shell extension page. Here is the link of it

- [Pixel Saver Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/)

Answer (score 0):

The extension is not compatible with Gnome-shell 3.10. But you can modify it like this :

1. replace the code of the `app_menu.js` (`/home/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/pixel-saver@deadalnix.me`) file with [this code](https://github.com/fmoralesc/pixel-saver/blob/4d6f8fb2b0fdb062257152ac1413484024d62cb0/pixel-saver@deadalnix.me/app_menu.js)
2. modify the file `metadata.js` (in the same folder) and add that the extension is compatible with Gnome 3.10.

use this code :

```
 "shell-version": [
    "3.4", 
    "3.6", 
    "3.8",
    "3.10"
 ],
```

Comment: Your link is dead, making your answer mostly useless now. Do you have a replacement link, by any chance?